# Trouble deciding to use variations or combinations in a task

Tags: combinatorics

A word TRAPEZOID is given. We are building words that are 5 letters long, with no repetitions.

a) All possibilites
b) How many words have at least one vowel?
c) How many words have 2 vowels and 3 consonants?


This task is under sector combinations in my book, but shouldn't at least a) be solved with variations?

My solution:
a) variations: $${9*8*7*6*5 = 15120}$$

b) variations (all possibilities - ones without the vowel): $${9*8*7*6*5 - 5*4*3*2*1 = 15000}$$
c) combinations: (2 vowels from 4 and 3 consonants from 5 + choosing the placing of letters): $$\binom{4}{2}*\binom{5}{3}*5!$$

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: a) and b) are OK but not c) since you're not considering where you place the letters.

Comment: @NeedForHelp I edited the post, is this right?

Comment: Yes, that update is good. You have "filled your bucket" with five letters, so the $5!$ is needed to order them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For c) you could proceed like this:

1. Pick $2$ of the $4$ vowels : $\binom{4}{2}$ choices
2. Pick $2$ of the $5$ available digits where you place the $2$ vowels chosen in 1.: $\binom{5}{2}$ choices.
3. Place the vowels at the $2$ digits chosen in 2.: $2!$ choices.
4. Pick $3$ of the $5$ consonants: $\binom{5}{3}$ choices.
5. Place the $3$ consonants chosen in 4. at the $3$ remaining digits (those different from the $2$ chosen in 2.): $3!$ choices.

All in all, you have (by the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product))
$$
\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2}\cdot2!\cdot\binom{5}{3}\cdot3!=7200
$$

such words.

Comment: Worth noting that this matches the update.

Comment: @Joffan Yeah, when you have chosen your $2$ vowels and $3$ consonants all you have to do is order them and there is $5!$ ways of doing so. So OP's solution is more efficient than mine!